# Measuring the time of a query

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using PDO, is there any way, to measure how long does it take to complete the query?

Comment: Please tell us about which database are you working with.

Comment: Oops right, I assumed MySQL, we need to know if it's really MySQL or not!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use microtime(true) to get the seconds needed to execute:

```
$start = microtime(true);
//Your code
echo 'Time needed: ' . (microtime(true) - $start) . '.';
```

To get a more accurate time you should do that test more times (10000 here):

```
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; ++$i) {
    //Your code
}
echo 'Time needed: ' . (microtime(true) - $start) . '.';
```

@Baz1nga, that code doesn't work, since microtime_float() isn't a function (Sorry, I can't comment, need more reputation :()

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using [Micro Time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) to measure the time. Just surround whatever you want to measure around this piece of code and you should get the time.

```
$time_start = microtime_float();

// code to be measured

$time_end = microtime_float();

$timeMeasured = $time_end - $time_start;


function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
```

Comment: please look at @Sietse answer, he's talking to you .

Answer (score 0):

As Sietse said, use the microtime function to measure the elapsed microseconds.

If you're testing MySQL before the test query, execute the following query:

```
RESET QUERY CACHE;
```

Otherwise, you can't be sure if the query was really executed or was retrieved from the query cache (it can be a big difference).